# Relationships and differences between typology and type and category theories?

Tags: category-theory, foundations, type-theory

From linguistics, I saw typology. By dictionary, typology is the study of or analysis or classification based on types or categories. So I was wondering if there are some relationships and differences between typology and type and category theories? Is typology the application of type and category theories in specific areas?

Answer (score 4):

[Typology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typology) is about classifying things, and is the name of a subfield of various fields like linguistics and anthropology, but it's essentially unrelated to mathematics.

[Type Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory) and [Category Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) are subfields of mathematics and theoretical computer science which are not really about classifying things at all, and are probably better summarized by Wikipedia than what I could come up with.

I do not recommend trying to make connections between academic fields of study via a general-purpose dictionary.